# Post-Uni Calculus/Probabilities Book Suggestion

Tags: calculus, probability, reference-request

I have a Computer Science Background, recently graduated and I would like to refresh/improve my knowledge about probabilities and statistics (also calculus). The priority is probabilities and statistics and then calculus. Can you suggest me any good books?

Also, is the * For Dummies series any good? They have Statistics and Probabilities books, and I do not know which one will be more useful for my programming abilities. Also I like calculus but the books I found were for high school level.

Any suggestions please? Thanks! (also I am looking at a price range of < 30 pounds.)

Comment: About probability, you want the one involving measure theory or not?

Comment: @newbie Perhaps he doesn't even know what is that.

Comment: @BandeiraGustavo Agreed, especially when he is considering using the "For Dummies" books...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Probability Theory and its Application Volume I by William Feller
and Calculus Volume I by Tom M Apostol.

Feller is an excellent book for Probability.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the digital textbook on probability at http://www.statlect.com . The level is intermediate an it gently introduces some measure theoretic concepts. The emphasis is on understanding things, providing step-by-step proofs and lots of solved exercises.